# Find the best function approximation to sine-like data

Tags: functions, mathematical-modeling, python, data-structure

I hope this is the right place to post this question. I have a dataset that comprised of individual sets of X,y.

Here are 3 examples:

[image]

As you can see, the X values range between 0 and ~140 and the y values range between ~0 and ~0.9. This and the general shape of the curve is the same for all sets, meaning that X cannot be a negative number and y cannot be above 1. I would like to find the best fit, the best general mathematical form that describes each set individually in an automated fashion. For example, if all my sets were somewhat linear, then the best fit would have been `y = ax+b`, and then I can use Python to find the best values for `a,b` for each set. The best function I was able to achieve was: `y = a*np.sin(b*(x-c))+d` , where `np.sin` is [Python Numpy sine function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sin.html), and a,b,c,d are parameters which, again, I can use Python to automatically iteratively find the best values.

Here is an example of the one fit of that function:

[image]

The fit is pretty good but I'm looking for something more agile/flexible mainly due to the part where `60 < x < 100` because this part is important as I would like the peak to be flatter and using sine limits the width of the peak. I tried polynomial functions but the results are not satisfying, they "suffer" from the same flexibility issue. I thought of maybe using Fourier transformation but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Try polynomial fits, $y=a+bx+cx^2 +dx^3\cdots$

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tried polynomial functions and it did not work well, they have the same flexibility issue.. I'll edit my question

Comment: i think polynomials would work as say you have the value of function at $n+1$ values then a $n$ degree polynomial exists

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi - I did not understand your comment, can you explain it again?

Comment: How many fit parameters do you think the data should have? Is there any particular functional form suggested by the type of data?

Comment: I think it can be neatly mapped on properly scaled Gaussian distributions.

Comment: Have you ever used splines ? It provides one of the easiest approximation means...

Comment: @Sal - I don't know how many parameters, the lower the better, the particular functional form is exactly what I am looking for and why I posted this question.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi- please note that the ascending and descending parts are not symmetrical, so a bell shape curve will not capture the shape as I want

Comment: @JeanMarie - no, I have not tried.. can you direct me to where I can find more information? preferably if it is in Python

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try but I'm afraid that this method will give a different number of parameters for each curve, and I would like to get a generic form of a function that will fit all curves, but I'll try it